# Read data from each column and finally print it in a row in perl

Tags: perl, file-handling, seek

I'm writing a script to read a large file(>10 GB) and write the data from an array to the end of each line in that file. Here is my code

```
   my $count=0;
   while(my $lines = <$FILE>){
        seek $FILE, length($lines), 1;
        print $FILE "\t", $array[$count];
        $count++;
        }
```

But I think I'm wrong in finding the end-of-line using seek method. I couldn't get my head around this. Can anyone please see whats wrong in this code.  before processing..

```
my 1st line
my 2nd line
my 3rd line
```

After processing....

```
my 1st line data1
my 2nd line data2
my 3rd line data3
```

data1,data2,data3 are in the @array.

Details on the code:

- FILE is opened in +< mode (read/write)
- FILE lines are tab delimited.
- @array holds the data1,2...

Issues:

- Moving the pointer to end of each line

Thanks,

Robin

Comment: Why not just create a new file with the data appended on each line?

Comment: Remember that the data you print isn't "inserted"; it simply overwrites whatever is already there. In a binary file with fixed-length records, that might be okay. In your case, it looks like you're overwriting current data (including newlines). It'd probably be easier to write out a second file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions _@Kenosis_ & _@rutter_. The problem here is that the file I'm writing will have millions of lines and 1000's of cols though i might start with the blank file. The file will have to  be written (lines * cols) times for all data arrays. This will be a performance bottle neck. So I'm trying to do this other way around to optimize the performance. I'll try _@Borodin_ suggestions and will update the thread soon!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. Seeking to a location in a file and then printing to it overwrites the data at that position.

I suggest you use [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile), which lets you access the contents of a file as an array, so appending to the end of a line of the file is done by simply adding a string to one of the elements of the array.

The code would look like this. Note that the line that creates `@newdata` is there just for testing. It creates an array that is the same length as the file, with lines like `data1`, `data2` etc. as you have in your question.

You should test this on a smaller file initially as it will take a while to process the 15GB file, and it also overwrites it, so if you have any bugs you will destroy your data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;
use Fcntl 'O_RDWR';

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'myfile', mode => O_RDWR or die $!;

my @newdata = map sprintf('data%d', $_ + 1), 0 .. $#file;

my $i = 0;
for my $line (@file) {
  $line .= "\t" . $newdata[$i];
  ++$i;
}

untie @file;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot _@Borodin_. It works!!. I just have a quick question here...When we tie a file to the array will the file data(lines) be stored in the memory??